# Reading words until an empty line

Tags: java

This following code executes correctly.I was wondering if there are better ways to write this code instead of using while(true) and break.For example using expressions,flags, do-while,etc.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Words {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

while(true){
    System.out.print("Type a word: ");
    String word = reader.nextLine();
    words.add(word);

if(word.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("You typed the following words:");
    for(String result: words){
    System.out.println(result);
    }
    break;
    }
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things in here that make sense. The first one is to use a function, and to return a List of words from that. The next thing is to use a do-while loop instead of a while loop... actually, truth is that I would personally use an assignment in the while condition. This is relatively uncommon, so let me explain:

```
private static List<String> readWords(Scanner source) {
    String word = null;
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!(word = source.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
        words.add(word);
    }
    return words;
}
```

That's a relatively complicated loop. It puts both the readline, and the loop-check in the same place. It reads the line in to `word`, then also makes sure that is not empty.

While the above is relatively uncommon to see, it makes the conditional really concise, and reduces duplicate checks.

Oh, and using a `forEach` on the resulting list makes the print really easy....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> words = readWords(new Scanner(System.in));
    words.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```